# How to load data for each pagination of the data table

Tags: jquery, python, datatable, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database table which has some thousands of rows and am developing a crud admin web app. Am using datatable to show all the rows(View All). When I load all the Rows using datatable it takes some 30 seconds to load the page. I want to avoid it using ajax pagination.

Python Code :

My python function for fetching all the rows from a tables is looks like this

```
 @companies.route('/list', methods=['GET'])
 @requires_session_auth
 def company_list():
    try:
       all_companies = Company.query.all()
       return render_template('company_list.html', company=all_companies)
    except:
    logger.exception('Error rendering Company list.')


 return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Html code:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% block subtitle %}Companies{% endblock %}
 {% block content %}

 <h2>Companies</h2>

 <table id="datatable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th align="center">Actions</th>
        <th align="left">ID</th>
        <th align="left">Label</th>
        <th align="left">Company Name</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     {% for image in images %}
     <tr>
       <td nowrap align="center">
        <a href="">Edit</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
         <a href="" class="del_link">Delete</a>
          </td>
          <td nowrap align="left">{{ company.id }}</td>
          <td nowrap align="left">{{ company.label }}</td>
          <td nowrap align="left">{{ company.companyname }}</td>
         </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
   </table>
  {% endblock %}
  {% block afterbody %}
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#datatable').dataTable({
         stateSave: true
       });
   </script>
  {% endblock %}
```

How can I create a python function which loads first 10 rows on the datatable and clicking the pagination button (2 nd page)it should load the next ten datas from the db table. How can I create python function and datatable in html. Here is the sample pagination https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html which is in php.

Comment: Have a look at the docs for datatable ajax api: [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax). In Flask you have to add something like SQLAlchemy's `paginate` function: [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this project https://github.com/Pegase745/sqlalchemy-datatables/tree/master/examples/flask_tut? It might be of help.

All that's needed is you running `pip install sqlalchemy-datatables`